# Why does the read() system call in my program result in several different possible outcomes?

Tags: c, io

I'm having some trouble comprehending exactly how read() works. For example, given the following program, with the file infile containing the string "abcdefghijklmnop":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
   int fd;
   char buf[5] = "WXYZ";
   fd = open("infile", O_RDONLY);
   read(fd, buf, 2);
   read(fd, buf+2, 2);
   close(fd);
   printf("%c%c%c%c\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);
   return 0;
}
```

Looking at the read system call function:

```
ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

I get that *buf is the buffer that holds the bytes read, and nbyte is the number of bytes that's being read. So after the first read(), only the first 2 characters of infile are read ("a" and "b"). Why isn't the output just "abcd"? Why are there other possibilities such as "aXbZ" or "abcZ"?

Comment: Re “Why isn't the output just "abcd"?”: When I run the program, the output is “abcd” and is just “abcd”, with a new-line character. What are you getting?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am also getting "abcd" when I run the program. This code was given by my professor in a lecture PPT slide, with the answer to his question "what are the possible outputs of the following program?" supposedly being "'abcd', 'aXbZ', 'abcZ', etc". I'm not sure why there are supposed to be other potential outputs.

Comment: The only way to tell how much you read is to look at the return value of the read call.

Comment: The other 'weird' outputs are possible if the read call is interrupted by a signal. In that case less than the number of requested bytes (2 in this case) will be written to the buffer. This is highly unlikely with regular files though.

Comment: @justanotherstudent May I ask why you deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469517/how-do-i-determine-how-many-processes-this-program-creates instead of accepting my answer? That's just rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual page for the version of `read` I have says:

> `read()` attempts to read `nbyte` bytes of data from the object referenced by the descriptor `fildes` into the buffer pointed to by `buf`.

and:

> Upon successful completion, `read()`, `readv()`, and `pread()` return the number of bytes actually read and placed in the buffer. The system guarantees to read the number of bytes requested if the descriptor references a normal file that has that many bytes left before the end-of-file, but in no other case.

Thus, in the case you describe, with “the file infile containing the string "abcdefghijklmnop"”, the two `read` calls are guarantee to put “ab” and “cd” into `buf`, so the program will print “abcd” and a new-line character. (I would not take that guarantee literally. Certainly the system can guarantee that it will not allow unrelated interrupts to prevent the `read` from completely reading the requested data, but it could not guarantee there is no hardware failure, such as a disk drive failing before the read is completed.)

In other situations, when `read` is reading from a source other than a normal file, each of the two `read` calls may read 0, 1, or 2 bytes. Thus, the possible buffer contents are:

| Bytes read in first read | Bytes read in second read | Buffer contents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | `WXYZ` |
| 0 | 1 | `WXaZ` |
| 0 | 2 | `WXab` |
| 1 | 0 | `aXYZ` |
| 1 | 1 | `aXbZ` |
| 1 | 2 | `aXbc` |
| 2 | 0 | `abYZ` |
| 2 | 1 | `abcZ` |
| 2 | 2 | `abcd` |

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Yes, thanks, fixed.